# Alfresco workflow api is loosing a variable

Tags: workflow, alfresco

I have an Alfresco community 5.2 installation with a custom workflow. The users needs to specify some actors to be part of this workflow and review the submitted document. The users are divided in 4 groups (co-authors, reviewers, approvers, authorizer) and I start the workflow using Alfresco JS Api passing all variables and actors.

The problem that I have is: a workflow variable of one of those actors group, the reviewers, is correctly passed to wf Params but is received as null when the workflow is started

```js
var wfparams = new Array();
wfparams["mywf:coAuthorsAssignees"] = coAuthorsProp;
wfparams["mywf:reviewersAssignees"] = reviewersProp;
wfparams["mywf:approverAssignee"] = approverProp;
wfparams["mywf:authorizerAssignee"] = authorizerProp;
wfparams["bpm:priority"] = workflowPriorityProp;
wfparams["mywf:taskDueDateDaysNumber"] = workflowTaskDueDateDaysNumberProp;
wfparams["bpm:description"] = workflowMessageProp;
wfparams["bpm:workflowDescription"] = workflowMessageProp;
wfparams["mywf:copyToInitiator"] = copyToInitiator;
wfparams["mywf:previousTaskComments"] = workflowInitiatorComment;
wfparams["_startTaskCompleted"] = new Date();

logger.info("mywf:reviewersAssignees"); // OK, the variable is correct

workflowAction.startWorkflow(package, wfparams);
```

And here is my start

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:activiti="http://activiti.org/bpmn" xmlns:bpmndi="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI" xmlns:omgdc="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DC" xmlns:omgdi="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DI" typeLanguage="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" expressionLanguage="http://www.w3.org/1999/XPath" targetNamespace="http://alfresco.org">
  <process id="DTTPublishWorkflow" name="Parallel Review And Approve Document" isExecutable="true">
    <extensionElements>
      <activiti:executionListener event="start" class="org.alfresco.repo.workflow.activiti.listener.ScriptExecutionListener">
        <activiti:field name="script">
          <activiti:string><![CDATA[//checkSingleWFIstance();
              // printing the variable inside the workflow (bpmn), I see it null
              logger.info(execution.getVariable('mywf_reviewersAssignees')) // null
<!-- ... -->
```

How it is possible? What am I missing?

Or what can I do to figure out what the problem is? Can I debug somehow that happens under `startWorkflow(package, wfparams);`

-- EDIT --

Could it be some strange problem in javascript object conversion ?

Comment: Hope all the group have users and please check those group during assignment in js and also check that property name.

Comment: what dou you mean with this 'Hope all the group have users' ?? Those groups are not mandatory. They can be empty. But the problem is the variable's value passed in the wfparams is lost. Can it be some javascript object type problem?

Comment: is every of your custom properties null or just this one?

Comment: sadly, just this one

Answer (score 0):

Look like some prefix mistake.
You are assigning by prefix "mywf" and you are fetching by "eneawf".
Is this your way of fetching or mistake?

Comment: Sadly it was only a type error when I pasted in Stackoverflow.... the read variable is correct and it is mywf_revieversAssignees